# Perl - How create method alias in child class?

Tags: perl, class

I'm trying to create an alias to a super class generic method in the child class, but it doesn't seem to work.  This trick inside the same class works, but it doesn't seem to work across the super/child transition.  Here is a real basic example.  The first two calls work.  The third call generates error about undefined subroutine.  I also tried using SUPER::cat, but that didn't work either.

```
package foo;

sub cat{
  print("inside foo\n");
}

*bird = \&cat;

package bar;

use base 'foo';

*dog = \&cat;

package main;

foo::cat();
foo::bird();
bar::dog();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
*dog = \&cat;
```

Should be:

```
*dog = \&foo::cat;
```

Comment: That does work.  I'm just not clear why I need it.  Shouldn't the "use base" import all the parent methods into my child class?

Comment: "use base" establishes an ISA relationship with base class

Answer (score 5):

You are confused between object-oriented inheritance and simple symbol importing.

As you say `use base 'foo'` declares a super-class. That means `foo` will be checked for any calls to methods that don't appear in `bar`.

However `*dog = \&cat` isn't a method call: it's simply a glob assignment, so the search won't go beyond `&bar::cat`.

If you were writing truly object-oriented code, then assigning to `*bar::dog` like that would defeat the point of the inheritance mechanism.

To observe Perl's object-oriented functionality, move the glob assignment to `foo` (where it is simply aliasing a method) and make the calls using method-call syntax.

In this code, `bar` has no methods of its own and inherits *everything* from `foo`, yet the code works as intended.

```
package foo;

sub cat {
  print("inside foo\n");
}

*bird = \&cat;
*dog = \&cat;


package bar;

use base 'foo';



package main;

bar->cat();
bar->bird();
bar->dog();
```

**output**

```
inside foo
inside foo
inside foo
```

Comment: +1: my comment became an answer of its own: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16070397/468327

Answer (score 2):

You should write

```
sub dog { shift->cat(@_) }
```

(basically eta-converting the `cat` method) instead of using glob assignment, so that a subclass of `bar` can override or extend `cat` without breaking `bar`'s contract that `cat` and `dog` do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the ideas Borodin has presented one step further, suppose you are doing proper OO but do want an alias for a method provided by a parent class, and only in this subclass (and deeper). In that case you might want this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package foo;

sub new { return bless {}, shift }

sub cat{
  print("inside foo\n");
}

*bird = \&cat;

package bar;

use base 'foo';

sub dog { $_[0]->can('cat')->(@_) }

package main;

my $bar = bar->new;
$bar->cat();
$bar->bird();
$bar->dog();
```

This mechanism preserves `dog` in the stack trace. If you don't want that, you can use the `goto &sub` form, but since you should only do that if you know why, I'm not going to put an example here.